# Angular 17 user-layout.component.ts:70 ERROR Error: NG0100

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to generate dynamically a sidebar using the template coreui with angular 17

The error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

```
ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: 
Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'disabled'. Expression location: \_SidebarNavLinkComponent component It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook? Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.mjs:11912:11)
at bindingUpdated (core.mjs:17587:17)
at ɵɵproperty (core.mjs:20396:9)
at SidebarNavLinkComponent_Template (coreui-angular.mjs:13043:14)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:12263:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:13490:13)
at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:13714:9)
at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (core.mjs:13677:5)
at detectChangesInComponent (core.mjs:13666:5)
at detectChangesInChildComponents (core.mjs:13727:9)
```

I'm trying to update the coreui sidebar dyanamically.
Here is my view layout.component.html

```
<!--sidebar-->
<c-sidebar #sidebar="cSidebar"
           class="d-print-none sidebar sidebar-fixed"
           id="sidebar"
           visible>

  <c-sidebar-brand [brandFull]="{
    src: 'assets/img/brand/Success-logo.svg',
    width: 200,
    height: 46,
    alt: 'Success sarl Logo'
  }"
                   [brandNarrow]="{
    src: 'assets/img/brand/coreui-signet-white.svg',
    width: 46,
    height: 46,
    alt: 'Success sarl Logo'
  }"
                   routerLink="./" />

  <ng-scrollbar pointerEventsMethod="scrollbar">
    <c-sidebar-nav [navItems]="navItems"
                   dropdownMode="close" />

  </ng-scrollbar>


  <c-sidebar-toggler *ngIf="!sidebar.narrow"
                     toggle="unfoldable"
                     cSidebarToggle="sidebar" />
</c-sidebar>

<!--main-->
<div class="wrapper d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 bg-light dark:bg-transparent">
  <!--app-header-->
  <app-default-header class="mb-4 d-print-none header header-sticky" position="sticky" sidebarId="sidebar" />
  <!--app-body-->
  <div class="body flex-grow-1 px-3">
    <c-container breakpoint="lg" class="h-auto">
      <router-outlet />
    </c-container>
  </div>
  <!--app footer-->
  <app-default-footer />
</div>
```

Here is my layout.component.ts

```
export class UserLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  public navItem?: Observable<any>;
  public navItems: any;
  public userAuthenticated = false;
  public showView: any;

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService,
    private _repository: RepositoryService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private sideBarGenerateService: SideBarGenerateService,
  ) {
    this._authService.loginChanged.subscribe(userAuthenticated => {
        this.userAuthenticated = userAuthenticated;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._authService.isAuthenticated().then(userAuthenticated => {
      this.userAuthenticated = userAuthenticated;
    });

    this._authService.checkUserClaims(Constants.adminClaims).then( res => {
      if (!res) {
        let user =  this._authService.getUserInfo();
        this._repository.getData(`api/v1/UserHasContrat/users/${this.route.snapshot.queryParams['filter']}`).subscribe((response: ApiHttpResponse) => {
          if (!(response.body?.every((elem: any) => (user.profile.sub).includes(elem?.userId)))) {
            this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          }
        });
      }
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.navItems = this.sideBarGenerateService.getSideBar();
    },0)
  }


}
```

My Service

```
    getSideBar = () => {
  //Get claims of user
  this.userClaims = this._authService.getUserInfo()['profile']['role'];

  return navItems.filter(this.isToBeDisplayed);
}

//Filter items to display
isToBeDisplayed = (value: any) => {
  if (value.hasOwnProperty('children') && value.children.length > 0) {
    value.children = value.children.filter((currentValue: any) => {
      if (currentValue?.attributes) {
        if ((currentValue.attributes['role'].every((elem: string) => this.userClaims.includes(elem)))) {
          return currentValue;
        }
      }
    })
    return value;
  }
  else {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Please help me check out this code. Can't have a result without ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.

Comment: Can't see your service. But the code you have in `ngOnInit` probably you need to hook in a later time in the lifecycle without the use of setTimeout.

Comment: Please check out the code again

Comment: @billybadass check out this please, have the same error usinig ngAfterViewInit without the use of setTimeout